# Two association tables in Python + Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to create a family tree, but I'm having a little trouble with the data model. I have one table that needs to refer to itself in two ways, one for the parent <-> child relationship, and one for the spouse relationship. I attempted the code below, but I'm getting an error of:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with
>   column 'spouses.so2_id' could not find table 'member' with which to
>   generate a foreign key to target column 'member_id'

Would anybody have any guidance? I attempted to read the docs on [Adjacency List Relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/self_referential.html), but got a little lost. Thank you for any help you can give!

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

# association table for parents<->children
children = db.Table('children',
                db.Column('child_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('member.member_id')),
                db.Column('parent_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('member.member_id'))
                )

# association table for spouses
spouses = db.Table('spouses',
               db.Column('so1_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('member.member_id')),
               db.Column('so2_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('member.member_id'))
               )


class Member(db.Model):
    """Node within the family tree."""

    __tablename__ = "members"

    member_id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    eng_title = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=True)
    alt_name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=True)
    lineage = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=True)
    deceased = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=True)
    image_url = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=True)
    parents = db.relationship('Member',
                          secondary=children,
                          primaryjoin=(children.c.child_id == member_id),
                          secondaryjoin=(children.c.parent_id == member_id),
                          backref=db.backref('children', lazy='dynamic'),
                          lazy='dynamic')
    spouse = db.relationship('Member',
                         secondary=spouses,
                         primaryjoin=(spouses.c.so1_id == member_id),
                         secondaryjoin=(spouses.c.so2_id == member_id),
                         backref=db.backref('spouses', lazy='dynamic'),
                         lazy='dynamic')
```

Comment: You are using the wrong name for your table in the `ForeignKey` references - it should be `db.ForeignKey('members.member_id')` since that's the table name you define for `Member`

Comment: @SeanVieira Aha! Silly me. That seemed to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I can help - welcome to StackOverflow!